# macOS Catalina software updates issue

Tags: xcode, software-update, homebrew

During parallel downloading Xcode and installing homebrew, I stopped installing Command Line Tools for Xcode. Now I can see in Software Update two items related to that. With different versions. After clicking <kbd>Update Now</kbd> I can see a progress bar. But finally, the message doesn't go and it proposes me update that 2 items again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to download the Command Line Tools 11.2 from [More Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). An Apple ID is required.

Install it manually and afterwards the pending (and obviously not installing) updates in Software Update will vanish.

As an alternative a direct d/l link: [Command Line Tools 11.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.2.dmg)